# Обработка нажатий по системному меню в UWP приложении на с++

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, winrt

Создаю пункты в меню через `InsertMenuItem` удалив перед этим старые пункты:

```
    HMENU systemMenu = GetSystemMenu(window, FALSE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        RemoveMenu(systemMenu, 0, 1024);
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    MENUITEMINFO alwaysOnTop;
    alwaysOnTop.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    alwaysOnTop.fMask = MIIM_DATA | MIIM_STRING;
    alwaysOnTop.fType = MFT_STRING;
    alwaysOnTop.dwTypeData = (char*) "Toggle Menu";
    alwaysOnTop.cch = 11;
    alwaysOnTop.wID = 5;
    alwaysOnTop.dwItemData  = 6;
    InsertMenuItem(systemMenu, cnt++, TRUE, &alwaysOnTop);
```

[image: 1]

Добавил, а обработать нажатие не могу, потому что это UWP приложение, а не win32, и соответственно использовать `WndProс` с `WM_SYSCOMMAND` не могу, пытался по гайдам сделать его рабочим через `SetWindowLongPtr` - `WndProc` стал принимать сообщения, но не те которые мне нужны, а сообщения по типу изменения размеров окна. Даже нажатия по клавиатуре не приходят, не говоря о `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. Можно ли средствами winrt обработать нажатие по системному меню? Пробовал принимать ивенты по типу KeyDown - там тоже пусто...

Comment: Когда ты вызываешь SetWindowLongPtr он тебе возвращает старое значение, ты его потом после отработки необходимого тебе сообщения передай в функцию `CallWindowProc`, и верни значение системе. То есть ты обработал нажатие на меню, а остальные сообщения верни окну, чтобы не сломать логику

Comment: `return CallWindowProcA(reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(oldSysMenuProc), w, nCode, wParam, lParam);` и так возращаю, всеровно ничего не менятеся

Comment: Покажи весь код

Comment: Так что, ты будешь добавлять весь код чтобы понять где у тебя проблема или нет?